# What is Minkowski problem?

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a question about 'Minkowski problem' related to Gaussian curvature.
I searched 'Minkowski problem' in Google, Almost all of them were related to Einstein's theory of relativity. So I ask about this here!

As far as I know, the Minkowski problem is:

> The classical Minkowski problem can be stated as follows: Given a
> smooth closed curve in the plane, can we find a convex, closed curve
> with the same length and the same Gaussian curvature at each point?
>
> At the time Minkowski posed this problem, there was a growing interest
> in the theory of curves and surfaces. Mathematicians were exploring
> various geometric properties of curves and surfaces, including
> curvature. The concept of Gaussian curvature, which measures the
> curvature of a surface at each point, had been developed by Carl
> Friedrich Gauss in the early 19th century.
>
> The difficulty that mathematicians faced when the classical Minkowski
> problem arose was finding a convex
> curve with the same length and the same Gaussian curvature.

But I'm not sure if this is correct, and even if this is correct, I want to know more about Minkowski problem's historical background and motivation, so I'm posting this question.

Comment: Have you looked at the book [**Convex Bodies: The Brunn−Minkowski Theory**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1107601010) by Rolf Schneider (2013, 2nd edition)? I don't know anything about this topic (nor do I have access to this book), but 2-3 minutes of googling led me to several places in which this book was recommended for historical information (for example, "*(or see [9] for history)*" in [this paper](http://sxzz.whu.edu.cn/html/2018/2/20180210.htm)).

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'll find it

Comment: Do you have a references? You must have read about it somewhere

Comment: To be honest, I used chat gpt.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems which can be called "Minkowski problem". Perhaps the most famous one is this problem from differential geometry:
[Minkowski Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_problem).